# Code Chef: Code Not Correct? Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11

Recently I've started doing Code Chef challenges to practice programming in C and C++ when I came across the ATM challenge. The challenge (which I expected to be relatively easy) was to create a program that withdraws money from a bank account if the withdrawal amount is a multiple of 5 and if the `withdraw > balance`. If the transaction is accepted it also charges a fee of 0.5, else it just reprints the bank data.

The link to the challenge is here:
https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

The program runs perfectly fine for me on my computer but for some reason it is wrong.

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

class Bank_data {
private:
  double balance;
public:
  void withdraw (int amount) {
    if (amount > balance - 0.5 || amount % 5 != 0)
      printf("%.2f\n", balance);
    else
      printf("%.2f\n", balance - amount - 0.5);
  }
  void setBalance (int amount) {
    balance = amount;
  }
};

int main () {

  Bank_data bd;
  int withdraw, init_val;

  cin >> std::fixed;
  cin >> std::setprecision(2) >> withdraw >> init_val;

  bd.setBalance (init_val);
  bd.withdraw (withdraw);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample io:

- I: 5 500
- O1: 494.50
- I2: 600 500
- O2: 500.00
- I3: 4 500
- O3: 500.00

Comment: You never change your balance after a withdrawal - seems a bit odd to me!

Comment: @John3136 It only runs once, then the program closes.